# htaccess friendly url tries to open index.php instead of parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)/?$ ./portfolio.php?project=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So when I try to open for example: `mywebsite.com/portfolio/my-project`, it has to go to `mywebsite.com/portfolio.php?project=my-project`.

But instead, my url changes to `mywebsite.com/portfolio/index.php`, which it can't open obviously, because that page doesn't exist. Why is it doing this?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: `if (isset($_GET['project'])) { ... } else header('Location: index.php')` at the top of my `portfolio.php` page, **was causing this**. So it seems as if my project won't get passed to the page, with the `$_GET['project']` request?

**Fixed**: Apparently, I needed `-MultiViews` in `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Comment: So where is `mywebsite.com/portfolio/my-project` supposed to go and how is the URL that is mapped to `index.php`? Please explain in detail all possibilities, with URL examples. It's hard to guess how the incoming URLs are and where are they supposed to be mapped to.

Comment: Does the URL in browser address bar actually change?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, mywebsite.com/portfolio/my-project, is changed to mywebsite.com/portfolio/index.php, every time.

Comment: This is probably a redirect and I do not see a redirect in the rules above. Something is wrong elsewhere, some other line in your .htaccess, some other .htaccess or in the portfolio.php page itself.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the redirect on the portfolio.php page, if the `$_GET['project']` wasn't set, caused this. Why isn't this working anymore? The path to my css file also seems to have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable MultiViews with

```
Options -MultiViews
```